# when i run :BundleInstall,I got an error in vim quickfix window

Tags: vim

when i run :BundleInstall,I got an error in vim quickfix window

> Error detected while processing ~/.vim/bundle/jshint.vim-Stelmach/plugin/jshint.vim:
>   Line 65:
>   Function JSHint already exists, add ! to replace it
>   Line 92:
>   Function 21_SetCursorLineColor already exists, add ! to replace it
>   Line 100:
>   Function 21_MaybeClearCursorLineColor already exists, add ! to replace it
>   Line 118:
>   Function 21_ClearCursorLineColor already exists, add ! to replace it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is very clear (and it's not displayed in the quickfix window): there's a `!` missing after the `function` keyword on line 65 of that file.

Add the `!` yourself and/or create an issue on the plugin's issue tracker and wait for the author to commit a fix.

Basically, Vim complains when an attempt is made to define a function with the same name as another pre-existing function. Appending a `!` after the `function` keyword makes Vim replace the old function with the new one.

Comment: @user1779774: Oops! I totally borked my copy/pasting: `function FuncName()` should be `function! FuncName()`. Sorry for my sloppiness.